# Galaxy S4 Can't Debug in Flash Pro or Flash Builder. Always connects as "Media Device"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5, galaxy

So I have been developing flash applications for a while now. I recently got a new phone (Samsung Galaxy S4), but I can't for the life of me debug an application on it. I went into the settings, did the hack where you keep tapping the model number, turned on developer mode, and turned on USB debugging.

However, every time I plug my phone in it says, "Connected as a media device"

Gaaah. I don't even use my phone as a media device! Can someone help me out. I just want to connect for debugging. What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the usb divers for you device?

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

I had the same problem then I changed mine from a media device(MTP) to a Camera(PTP) which fixed it for me

Comment: Brilliant. The switch to Camera mode was what was required (who would have guessed?) and then Windows showed me my device driver was missing, so I downloaded that from the link you provided. We're up and running baby.